# Django1.5 Custom Users table

Tags: python, database, django, django-1.5

I'm trying to create a custom `auth_users` table with Django 1.5 following the intructions here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user

But the code below doesn't seem to be working even though I have set the new columns it should contain. 
It still creates the same default table even after dropping the full database and `python manage.py syncdb`

I have read several documents and that is what I have right now:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser

    class User(AbstractBaseUser):    
        identifier = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
        last_name  = models.CharField(max_length=254)

        USERNAME_FIELD = 'identifier'
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name','last_name']
```

This `models.py` is installed in `settings.py`

**settings.py**

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODEL = 'myaccount.User'
```

This doesn't make any effect to the table, but it **creates a new one called myaccount_user**.

What's wrong with that? What should I change in order to modify `auth_user` table instead of creating a new one?

Comment: Can you paste the full model please? and also you have `myaccount` into `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres added the missing imports in the `models.py`. And yes, I have 'myaccount' in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: I found the error see my answer

Answer (score 0):

The error is that should be `AUTH_PROFILE_MODEL = 'myaccount.User'` instead of `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'myaccount.User'`

Also you forgot a bunch of methods in your Model and a `USERNAME_FIELD`

see [a full example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) of how to build your own `CUSTOM USER`

Comment: With the code till EDIT I get no errors but I still get the default tables. With the code after EDIT clash error.

Comment: Well Some errors can be you have not specified a `USERNAME_FIELD` yet
and a bunch of methods.

Comment: Not working either. But I've just notice that instead of modifying `auth_user`, it is creating a new table `myaccount_user`